# Add extra element to existing array

Tags: angular

Actual Data:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]

   0: {Capacity: "150", Series: "20", Make: "150", Model: "150", TowerHeight: "151", …}

   1: {Capacity: "250", Series: "250", Make: "250", Model: "252", TowerHeight: "250", …}

   2: {Capacity: "151", Series: "21", Make: "151", Model: "151", TowerHeight: "152", …}
```

I want to add an extra element to this array. Please help me with this case:
Add `Disabled: true` for every element.

I want Output below like this:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]

   0: {Disabled: true, Capacity: "150", Series: "20", Make: "150", Model: "150", TowerHeight: "151", …}

   1: {Disabled: true, Capacity: "250", Series: "250", Make: "250", Model: "252", TowerHeight: "250", …}

   2: {Disabled: true, Capacity: "151", Series: "21", Make: "151", Model: "151", TowerHeight: "152", …}
```

Comment: Hi, really thanks a lot.
your answer helped me lot.
thanks again...

Comment: Hi... I have another question.

I got a response from server as below:
CreatedDate: "2020-06-25T00:00:00.000Z"

when I display data in an HTML table

<td> {{slot.CreatedDate | date:"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"}} </td>

the date will be shown as "25-06-2020 05:30"

But I need output like this
25-06-2020 00:00
which I have received from the server.
Please suggest to me. thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you:

```
const result = data.map(item => { return {...item, Disabled: true} })
```

Comment: Hi, really thanks a lot.
your answer helped me lot.
thanks again...

Comment: Hi... I have another question.

I got a response from server as below:

CreatedDate: "2020-06-25T00:00:00.000Z"

when I display data in an HTML table

<td> {{slot.CreatedDate | date:"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"}} </td>

the date will be shown as "25-06-2020 05:30"

But I need output like this
25-06-2020 00:00
which I have received from the server.
Please suggest to me. thanks...

Comment: Please reference this: https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/angular-date-pipe-formatting-date-times-in-angular-with-examples/ It will help you. Please upvote and check it solved if my solution helped you. thank you

Comment: Hi Fro...
It is used for only format the date, but here the problem is time added to +5:30 hrs for received time.

If u don't mine please ping me at +91-9333355552 to this number.
I wil explain u.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 2+ this should be simple

[Click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/IZ01jkWhzg8KAjHs?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1) for the Plunker solution

Also adding the code below:

```
this.list = [
  {Capacity: "150", Series: "20", Make: "150", Model: "150", TowerHeight: "151"},
  {Capacity: "250", Series: "250", Make: "250", Model: "252", TowerHeight: "250"},
  {Capacity: "151", Series: "21", Make: "151", Model: "151", TowerHeight: "152"}
  ];


this.newlist = this.list.map(item => { return {Disabled: true, ...item} })
```

Adding output below:

**OLD List:**

```
[
    {
        "Capacity": "150",
        "Series": "20",
        "Make": "150",
        "Model": "150",
        "TowerHeight": "151"
    },
    {
        "Capacity": "250",
        "Series": "250",
        "Make": "250",
        "Model": "252",
        "TowerHeight": "250"
    },
    {
        "Capacity": "151",
        "Series": "21",
        "Make": "151",
        "Model": "151",
        "TowerHeight": "152"
    }
]
```

**NEW List:**

```
[
    {
        "Disabled": true,
        "Capacity": "150",
        "Series": "20",
        "Make": "150",
        "Model": "150",
        "TowerHeight": "151"
    },
    {
        "Disabled": true,
        "Capacity": "250",
        "Series": "250",
        "Make": "250",
        "Model": "252",
        "TowerHeight": "250"
    },
    {
        "Disabled": true,
        "Capacity": "151",
        "Series": "21",
        "Make": "151",
        "Model": "151",
        "TowerHeight": "152"
    }
]
```